# PuTTY secure copy client | -bash: pscp: command not found |

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty, pscp

I am trying to learn the Amazon's AWS - EC2 service and was following its tutorial (at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html)  
I have successfully launched an instance and am on Step:2, Connect to your instance.  I got PuTTY and followed the tutorial for connection using PuTTY (at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html)  
Here I am unable to use the command - **pscp -i C:\path\my-key-pair.ppk C:\path\Sample_file.txt ec2-user@public_dns:/home/ec2-user/Sample_file.txt** as it shows the following error : ' **-bash: pscp: command not found** '

My main aim is to use an online free temporary server to host a RESTful API that I have made and tested on localhost in python3.

I am a beginner in this field and would like some help.

Thank you.

Comment: pscp (and putty) are Windows programs. Which OS is running on your computer?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Comment: If you installed putty using the standard 64-bit MSI installer, it installs into C:\Program Files\PuTTY\ on your Windows computer. It also adds that location to your PATH. Start a new command prompt on your Windows computer and run pscp.

Comment: It works, thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pscp` is Windows program.

You are not supposed to use it in PuTTY terminal (on the virtual machine shell), but on your local Windows machine.